# Why assigning textContent to a reference does not update the DOM when reference is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It looks like textContent is a property in Node, but why the below code doesn't work as expected:

http://jsbin.com/ukexab/1/edit

```
var d = document.getElementById("container");

var data = {text: "something different"};

d.textContent = data.text;

data.text = "new text";
```

Is this something like copying and not referencing?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript uses assign and pass by value, not by reference.

Comment: You need to re-assign the values on change. d.textContent = "new text";

Comment: @FelixKling That isn't true for Objects and Arrays?

Comment: @Jeff: Well, in that case the value is a reference to the object/array. Pass by reference actually means that a reference *to the variable itself* is passed or assigned (and that's not how JS works). More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy.

Comment: @Jeff: For example, lets assume that `data.text` was an object, and not a string. Would it make a difference? No, because `data.text` is assigned a new value and `d.textContent` still refers to the old value, no matter whether it is an object or a primitive data type.

Comment: @FelixKling I see what you mean in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's due to how assignment works.

Assigning an `Object` or anything derived from it to a variable will actually assign a reference to that object, and increase the object's reference count.

Assigning a primitive will pass a copy of its value.